# Swipe-able Left Sidemenu with Homeview Gaussian blur effect IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, side-menu, gaussianblur

[image]

I was looking for framework which provides left sidemenu that is open either by clicking left arrow button or by swiping in right direction and once swiping begun homeview gets blurred(using gaussian blur effect) as shown in image.

It will be great help if anyone can suggest framework supportive with objective c which provide expected behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself, it will take a day or two to implement this kind of behaviour.

Comment: I had already try to implement similar behaviour using MFSidemenu but its not provide exactly same as I was looking for hence I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

@Drashti, please this controller [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) 
   Then please add UIView.Animate with a set decrease alpha of self.view
at the time of Menu sideshow and at the time of menu side hide set alpha to 1 with same as animate

Comment: I want gaussian blur effect but this code might provide static blur effect.So I predict this won't  work.

Comment: I already tried.Once you put this code it will immediately make your right view blur instead of this I need blur effect which gradually increase blurring intensity you may check using [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16wsTCDHYPSMPxBZvWkEdj5B3cxIEe34_/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved required behaviour using framework [LGSideMenuController](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController)

Comment: Ok great, Keep it up